# Every 3rd column associated with one another

Tags: sql, excel, csv, geography

I have a table similar to below. Essentially, I have a variable called WC and the associated latitude and longitude columns to the right. Every third column is a new observation. At the very last column, I have another observation (longitude).

What I am trying to do is create a new column that is find the average of all the WC that are within 2 degrees of DL. Any idea how to do this using Excel or SQL?

```
Day WC   nlat elon WC2  nlat3 elon4 WC5  nlat6 elon7 WC8  nlat9 elon10  DL
1   0.7  34   -96  0.8  35    -98   0.5  37    -95   0.3  36    -102    -96
2   0.8  34   -96  0.7  35    -98   0.4  37    -95   0.3  36    -102    
3   0.7  34   -96  0.5  35    -98   0.3  37    -95   0.4  36    -102    -99
4   0.9  34   -96  0.8  35    -98   0.6  37    -95   0.5  36    -102    -100
5   0.6  34   -96  0.5  35    -98   0.5  37    -95   0.4  36    -102
```

Thanks

Comment: Textual data is favourable

Comment: Hi GurV and pintxo, sorry, this is my first post here. I tried a statement like UPDATE table1 SET newcolumn = (SELECT (WC, WC2, WC5, WC8) FROM table1 WHERE (elon, elon4, elon7, elon10)... but then realized that such a statement would do me no good. I'm kind of a newbie at SQL. I also considered a pivot table, however, since I have it in a dailyformat (each row is a day), not sure if that would work. Appreciate any advice or help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [table] ADD [newcolumn] AS (wc + wc2 + ...) / n
```